# How to serve scaled images in blogger

Tags: javascript, html, css, blogger

When I check my blog in Gtmetrix it shows 0 value for "serve scaled images". I don't know how to show scaled images in blogger. I tried many codes from fellow bloggers but still, it shows 0 value in "serve scaled images".
My link is [here](https://hobby-indoor.blogspot.in/).
Should I keep the same thumbnail size for homepage and post pages or anything else?
I don't know how to solve this matter.

The code used for resizing the images is as follows -

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
//<![CDATA[
  function snippetimage(a,e){var g=416,i=312;return image_tag='<img src="'+a.replace("/s72-c/","/w"+g+"-h"+i+"-p/")+'" alt="'+e+'"/>',yimage_tag='<img src="'+a.replace("default","0")+'" alt="'+e+'"/>',-1!=a.indexOf("img.youtube.com")?yimage_tag:""!=a?image_tag:""}
//]]>
</script>
```

Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue is happening because a larger than required image is being loaded by the template. You will have to change the resolution of the image (from the current **416x312** px to **183x200** px, as mentioned by the GTmetrix report shown in the screenshot below ). You will have to change the above code as follows -

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
//<![CDATA[
  function snippetimage(a,e){var g=183,i=200;return image_tag='<img src="'+a.replace("/s72-c/","/w"+g+"-h"+i+"-p/")+'" alt="'+e+'"/>',yimage_tag='<img src="'+a.replace("default","0")+'" alt="'+e+'"/>',-1!=a.indexOf("img.youtube.com")?yimage_tag:""!=a?image_tag:""}
//]]>
</script>
```

[image: gtmetrix report]

Comment: thank you so much @Prayag, It worked like charm. Thank you very much. But now it shows some other errors as well where I am scoring 0 in Gtmetrix. First is "Add expiry headers" and second is "minify javascript and css". Can you please provide solution for this?